# What are the tax implications for leftover financial aid and scholarship money?

Tags: united-states, taxes, college, scholarship

Previous semester as an undergraduate student, I won a pretty big scholarship from my university. So, along with the Pell Grant and other state grants/scholarships, that amount was also applied to my tuition and book fees this semester, and the rest was reimbursed to me.

As far as I know, and correct me if I'm wrong, any scholarship or grant money that is not used for educational costs (books, tuition, equipment, etc.) is taxable. Now, I was reimbursed a total of $3k for this semester. Some of that money will go towards transportation and food, and some money will be leftover. Though the total amount of money I receive is still less than the COA, the $3k I was reimbursed will go towards non-educational costs.

So would my $3k be considered taxable income? If so, would the income be considered earned or unearned when it comes to determining whether I need to file a tax return? If its considered earned, than I might not need to report it based on current limits. Also, I am filed as a dependent. Does that change anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's taxable. Confirm it with this [IRS free tool](https://www.irs.gov/help/ita/do-i-include-my-scholarship-fellowship-or-education-grant-as-income-on-my-tax-return).

See if you can apply more of the money to qualified, required educational expenses. If you can reduce the $3k in unearned income to $2100, there will be [no need to fill out Form 8615](https://www.thetaxadviser.com/issues/2019/jul/kiddie-tax-unearned-income-scholarships.html) (the kiddie tax).

You may be able to claim an [educational tax credit](https://collegefinance.com/financial-aid/is-pell-grant-income-taxable), in any case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do have two questions though. In the article you have linked, it talks about how the gross unearned income is reduced by the dependent's standard deduction. It provides an example with a student using $18k for non-education purposes and $12,200 is subtracted from it to only yield $5800 taxable income. What is that deduction for? Also, would I be able to get education tax credits if I don't file a tax return?

Comment: There's another IRS free tool for "do I have to file?": https://www.irs.gov/help/ita/do-i-need-to-file-a-tax-return   If the answer is 'yes', then using tax software should help you figure out how the deductions work, after you enter "Yes, I can be claimed as a dependent" in the tax software.

Comment: Okay, so when I use that IRS tool, I list the $3k as unearned income right?

Comment: Yes, that is right.